# What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iife

I would like to know what this means:

```
(function () {

})();
```

Is this basically saying `document.onload`?

Comment: btw, although you will see people calling this function 'self-invoking', that's clearly not true. The term [tag:iife] has the advantage of accuracy.

Comment: This gives a great explanation of this construct. It's also where the term "IIFE" originated. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is the point of this function construct? Why is it needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815757/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-this-function-construct-why-is-it-needed)

Comment: For the naming of this construct, also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3720283/1048572). Read about the [purpose of this construct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572), and a [technical explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4212149/1048572) (as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441498/1048572)).
For the syntax, have a look at [why the parenthesis are necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572) and [where they should go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3384504/1048572).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 980, accepted):

It’s an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), or [**IIFE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) for short. It executes immediately after it’s created.

It has nothing to do with any event-handler for any events (such as `document.onload`).
Consider the part within the first pair of parentheses: `(function(){})();`....it is a regular function expression. Then look at the last pair `(function(){})();`, this is normally added to an expression to call a function; in this case, our prior expression.

This pattern is often used when trying to avoid polluting the global namespace, because all the variables used inside the IIFE (like in any other *normal* function) are not visible outside its scope.
This is why, maybe, you confused this construction with an event-handler for `window.onload`, because it’s often used as this:

```
(function(){
  // all your code here
  var foo = function() {};
  window.onload = foo;
  // ...
})();
// foo is unreachable here (it’s undefined)
```

**Correction suggested by [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa):**

> The function is executed right after it's created, not after it is parsed. The entire script block is parsed before any code in it is executed. Also, parsing code doesn't automatically mean that it's executed, if for example the IIFE is inside a function then it won't be executed until the function is called.

**Update**
Since this is a pretty popular topic, it's worth mentioning that IIFE's can also be written with [ES6's arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (like [Gajus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368691/gajus) has pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript/8228308#comment43521302_8228308)) :

```
((foo) => {
 // do something with foo here foo
})('foo value')
```

Comment: @gion_13 what is the difference between the creation phase and parse phase?

Comment: @jlei the way I see it, a js program's life cycle includes the following phases: parsing, creation/compilation, execution. Although the actual implementation (and naming :)) ) may differ from browser to browser, we can determine these phases in our code by watching out for parsing errors, hoisting and run time errors. I personally haven't found many resources on this because it's too low level and it's not something that the programmer can control. You can find some sort of explanation in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34562772/491075

Comment: @sam firat of all, there's the varianle declaration and the new keyword. This means that in your example you are instantiating a new obiect defined by it's constructor (anonymous function expression) and it's invoked via the new operator, not by calling the finction as in the IIFE example. Sure that function acts like a closure for it's contents but It's by far a different use case.

Comment: How is this polluting the global namespace? foo is not available outside the function anyways.

`function(){
    var foo = '5';
}`

Comment: @Pankaj — Taken by itself, that is not even syntactically valid JS (it is a function expression but not in expression context so is treated as a syntax error).

Comment: it's important to note that IFFE's were useful because of the `var` keyword, which was global scoped. Therefore JS developers had to find a way to 'limit' variables in their code.

Comment: Another advantage is that we could call return anywhere to move out of the block of code which would be ugly otherwise.

Answer (score 127):

It's just an anonymous function that is executed right after it's created.

It's just as if you assigned it to a variable, and used it right after, only without the variable:

```
var f = function () {
};
f();
```

In jQuery there is a similar construct that you might be thinking of:

```
$(function(){
});
```

That is the short form of binding the `ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

But the above two constructs are not **IIFE**s.

Comment: The last two aren't really IIFEs, since they're invoked when the DOM is ready and not *immediately*

Comment: @swordofpain: Yes, that is correct, they are not IIFEs.

Comment: @swordofpain considering the second snippet; would there be any value in add () to the end of the function by turning it into an IIFE?

Comment: Is the semicolon at the end necessary?

Comment: @FrenkyB Not necessary, no, but encouraged (semicolons are frequently not actually necessary in Javascript, but it's good practice).  Each of those are statements that happen to include anonymous functions, rather than being function declarations.

Comment: Is there a different between your first example and naming the function (without assigning it to a variable):
`function f() {
};
f();`

Comment: @Guffa It doesn't have to be anonymous (although there is no point in naming it).

Also, for it to be an IIFE, the function expression and the invocation have to be in a single statement. In the example you've shown, they are on separate statements.

Answer (score 70):

An immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) immediately calls a function. This simply means that the function is executed immediately after the completion of the definition.

Three more common wordings:

```
// Crockford's preference - parens on the inside
(function() {
  console.log('Welcome to the Internet. Please follow me.');
}());

//The OPs example, parentheses on the outside
(function() {
  console.log('Welcome to the Internet. Please follow me.');
})();

//Using the exclamation mark operator
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654929/1175496
!function() {
  console.log('Welcome to the Internet. Please follow me.');
}();
```

If there are no special requirements for its return value, then we can write:

```
!function(){}();  // => true
~function(){}(); // => -1
+function(){}(); // => NaN
-function(){}();  // => NaN
```

Alternatively, it can be:

```
~(function(){})();
void function(){}();
true && function(){ /* code */ }();
15.0, function(){ /* code */ }();
```

You can even write:

```
new function(){ /* code */ }
31.new function(){ /* code */ }() //If no parameters, the last () is not required
```

Comment: last one `31.new`' is invalid syntax

Comment: Why are there so many ways to write the same thing?!! >_< I don't like this language

Comment: aaand the winner is `;(function(){}());`

Comment: The Crockford preference explanation was very useful - explains the differences I've seen in the wild, e.g. The [jQuery tiny-pubsub gist](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/661855/revisions#diff-2a13b376d239e937e9a50431520cfe2a) switched from one version to the other (you can see the change at the end of the file) and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Glad it provided different variations of syntax. It'd be nice like @Awesome_girl said, if there were fewer ways to do the same thing... but, I suppose many of these techniques are "code golf" ways of exploiting operators in ways they aren't commonly used; often to minimize amount of code.

Comment: @Awesome_girl: It's not that there are many ways to write the same thing; it's that JS has a loose type system with operators that can operate on any value type. You can do `1 - 1` and you can just as easily do `true - function(){}`. It's only one thing (an infix subtraction operator) but with different, even  nonsensical operands.

Comment: IIFE's are use also used for `new` keyword to pass array of args to a`new ClassName` function: `return new (ClassName.bind.apply(ClassName, [void 0].concat(args)))();`

Comment: Whats the benefit of using Crockford's function (function(){}()) over the others?

Answer (score 48):

That construct is called an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)** which means it gets executed immediately. Think of it as a function getting called automatically when the interpreter reaches that function.

**Most Common Use-case:**

One of its most common use cases is to limit the scope of a variable made via `var`. Variables created via `var` have a scope limited to a function so this construct (which is a function wrapper around certain code) will make sure that your variable scope doesn't leak out of that function.

In following example, `count` will not be available outside the immediately invoked function i.e. the scope of `count` will not leak out of the function. You should get a `ReferenceError`, should you try to access it outside of the immediately invoked function anyway.

```
(function () { 
    var count = 10;
})();
console.log(count);  // Reference Error: count is not defined
```

**ES6 Alternative (Recommended)**

In ES6, we now can have variables created via `let` and `const`. Both of them are block-scoped (unlike `var` which is function-scoped).

Therefore, instead of using that complex construct of IIFE for the use case I mentioned above, you can now write much simpler code to make sure that a variable's scope does not leak out of your desired block.

```
{ 
    let count = 10;
}
console.log(count);  // ReferenceError: count is not defined
```

In this example, we used `let` to define `count` variable which makes `count` limited to the block of code, we created with the curly brackets `{...}`.

I call it a “Curly Jail”.

Comment: I like the **Curly Jail** naming. Maybe it will stick :)

Answer (score 34):

That is saying execute immediately.

so if I do:

```
var val = (function(){
     var a = 0;  // in the scope of this function
     return function(x){
         a += x;
         return a;
     };
})();

alert(val(10)); //10
alert(val(11)); //21
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LqvpQ/

---

#### Second Example:

```
var val = (function(){
     return 13 + 5;
})();

alert(val); //18
```

Comment: I dont get it what does that prove its self invoking?

Comment: @Exitos because it returns that function. Ill give a second example.

Comment: very easy to understand +1

Answer (score 33):

It declares an anonymous function, then calls it:

```
(function (local_arg) {
   // anonymous function
   console.log(local_arg);
})(arg);
```

Comment: I guess "arguments" are outer variables that are referenced as "arg" to be used in local context within function?

Comment: @Dalibor `arguments` is [special](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments); my guess is the answerer just flipped where the names go

Answer (score 18):

```
(function () {
})();
```

This is called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). One of the famous JavaScript design patterns, it is the heart and soul of the modern day Module pattern. As the name suggests it executes immediately after it is created. This pattern creates an isolated or private scope of execution.

JavaScript prior to ECMAScript 6 used lexical scoping, so IIFE was used for simulating block scoping. (With ECMAScript 6 block scoping is possible with the introduction of the `let` and `const` keywords.)
[Reference for issue with lexical scoping](https://gist.github.com/gurucharanmk/5071d37bb5af61a93562fbe024a975de)

[Simulate block scoping with IIFE](https://gist.github.com/gurucharanmk/38d8557147d2f542d553b75dfeb40709)

The performance benefit of using IIFE’s is the ability to pass commonly used global objects like `window`, `document`, etc. as an argument by reducing the scope lookup. (Remember JavaScript looks for properties in local scope and way up the chain until global scope). So accessing global objects in local scope reduces the lookup time like below.

```
(function (globalObj) {
//Access the globalObj
})(window);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing gist to understand second parenthesis in IIFE. 
Also for clarifying lookup time benefit of global variable by defining them in definition

Answer (score 16):

This is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression in Javascript:

To understand IIFE in JS, lets break it down:

1. **Expression**: Something that returns a value 
   Example: Try out following in chrome console. These are expressions in JS.

> ```
> a = 10 
> output = 10 
> (1+3) 
> output = 4
> ```

2. **Function Expression**: 
   Example:

> ```
> // Function Expression 
> var greet = function(name){
>    return 'Namaste' + ' ' + name;
> }
>
> greet('Santosh');
> ```

**How function expression works:** 
- When JS engine runs for the first time (Execution Context - Create Phase), this function (on the right side of = above) does not get executed or stored in the memory. Variable 'greet' is assigned 'undefined' value by the JS engine. 
- During execution (Execution Context - Execute phase), the funtion object is created on the fly (**its not executed yet**), gets assigned to 'greet' variable and it can be invoked using 'greet('somename')'.

**3. Immediately Invoked Funtion Expression:**

Example:

```
// IIFE
var greeting = function(name) {
    return 'Namaste' + ' ' + name;
}('Santosh')

console.log(greeting)  // Namaste Santosh.
```

**How IIFE works**: 
- Notice the '()' immediately after the function declaration. Every funtion object has a 'CODE' property attached to it which is callable. And we can call it (or invoke it) using '()' braces. 

- So here, during the execution (Execution Context - Execute Phase), **the function object is created and its executed at the same time**
- So now, the greeting variable, instead of having the funtion object, has its return value ( a string )

**Typical usecase of IIFE in JS:**

The following IIFE pattern is quite commonly used.

```
// IIFE 
// Spelling of Function was not correct , result into error
(function (name) {
   var greeting = 'Namaste';
   console.log(greeting + ' ' + name);
})('Santosh');
```

- we are doing two things over here.
  a) Wrapping our function expression inside braces (). This goes to tell the syntax parser the whatever placed inside the () is an expression (function expression in this case) and is a valid code. 
  b) We are invoking this funtion at the same time using the () at the end of it.

***So this function gets created and executed at the same time (IIFE).***

**Important usecase for IIFE:**

**IIFE keeps our code safe.**  
- IIFE, being a function, has its own execution context, meaning all the variables created inside it are local to this function and are not shared with the global execution context.

Suppose I've another JS file (test1.js) used in my applicaiton along with iife.js (see below).

```
// test1.js

var greeting = 'Hello';

// iife.js
// Spelling of Function was not correct , result into error
(function (name) { 
   var greeting = 'Namaste';
   console.log(greeting + ' ' + name);
})('Santosh');

console.log(greeting)   // No collision happens here. It prints 'Hello'.
```

So IIFE helps us to **write safe code where we are not colliding with the global objects unintentionally.**

Comment: If we create functions inside IIFE how can we access them in some other js or jsx file i.e in react component.

Comment: Even though we didn't use IIFE, the greeting variable will not collide on the global greeting variable. So what is the advantage there?

Answer (score 15):

No, this construct just creates a scope for naming. If you break it in parts you can see that you have an external

```
(...)();
```

That is a function invocation. Inside the parenthesis you have:

```
function() {}
```

That is an anonymous function. Everything that is declared with **var** inside the construct will be visible only inside the same construct and will not pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 8):

That is a **self-invoking anonymous function**.

Check out the [W3Schools explanation of a self-invoking function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp).

> Function expressions can be made "self-invoking".
>
> A self-invoking expression is invoked (started) automatically, without
>   being called.
>
> Function expressions will execute automatically if the expression is
>   followed by ().
>
> You cannot self-invoke a function declaration.

Comment: `(function named(){console.log("Hello");}());` <-- self-executing *named* function

Comment: @bryc why would you gonna name a function that doesnt need a name.

Comment: @RicardoGonzales Recursion I guess

Answer (score 6):

This is the self-invoking anonymous function. It is executed while it is defined. Which means this function is defined and invokes itself immediate after the definition.

And the explanation of the syntax is: The function within the first `()` parenthesis is the function which has no name and by the next `();` parenthesis you can understand that it is called at the time it is defined. And you can pass any argument in this second `()` parenthesis which will be grabbed in the function which is in the first parenthesis. See this example:

```
(function(obj){
    // Do something with this obj
})(object);
```

Here the 'object' you are passing will be accessible within the function by 'obj', as you are grabbing it in the function signature.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer and your answer does not add anything that has not already been covered by the accepted answer. Hence, there was absolutely no need to write this answer.

Comment: I like reading multiple answers, sometimes the phrasing of one or the other makes a difference.

Comment: I thought it added because it let me know what that second set of parenthesis were for.  At least it was clearer here that I saw.

Comment: My fav ans.  Both ends of the sample IIFE have parameters, and the mapping between the two is made plain.

Answer (score 6):

Start here:

```
var b = 'bee';
console.log(b);  // global
```

Put it in a function and it is *no longer global* -- your primary goal.

```
function a() {
  var b = 'bee';
  console.log(b);
}
a();
console.log(b);  // ReferenceError: b is not defined -- *as desired*
```

Call the function immediately -- oops:

```
function a() {
  var b = 'bee';
  console.log(b);
}();             // SyntaxError: Expected () to start arrow function, but got ';' instead of '=>'
```

Use the parentheses to avoid a syntax error:

```
(function a() {
  var b = 'bee';
  console.log(b);
})(); // OK now
```

You can leave off the function name:

```
(function () {    // no name required
  var b = 'bee';
  console.log(b);
})();
```

It doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: The syntax error is talking about arrow functions. As I understand, it is a new feature of js, and it didn't exists some years ago, but the IIFE did. So, the parenthesis probably were used originally to avoid a syntax error, but a different?

Comment: Could you please answer @JCarlos question? As he quite rightly points out that the IIFE came a lot before the arrow function, it would help understand why the wrapping is required.

Comment: @Script47 I don't have an answer to JCarlos' question in the comment. You could formulate a new question and post it, and I'm sure you will get some good answers.

Comment: @JCarlos when I execute the one which throws the error, I actually get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` rather than any mention of arrow function. Could you possibly share a fiddle with it throwing the arrow function error?

Answer (score 5):

It is a function expression, it stands for Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). IIFE is simply a function that is executed right after it is created. So insted of the function having to wait until it is called to be executed, IIFE is executed immediately. Let's construct the IIFE by example. Suppose we have an add function which takes two integers as args and returns the sum
lets make the add function into an IIFE,

Step 1: Define the function

```
function add (a, b){
    return a+b;
}
add(5,5);
```

Step2: Call the function by wrap the entire functtion declaration into parentheses

```
(function add (a, b){
    return a+b;
})
//add(5,5);
```

Step 3:  To invock the function immediatly just remove the 'add' text from the call.

```
(function add (a, b){
    return a+b;
})(5,5);
```

**The main reason** to use an IFFE is to preserve a private scope within your function. Inside your javascript code you want to make sure that, you are not overriding any global variable. Sometimes you may accidentaly define a variable that overrides a global variable. Let's try by example. suppose we have an html file called iffe.html and codes inside body tag are-

```
<body>
    <div id = 'demo'></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    </script> 
</body>
```

Well, above code will execute with out any question, now assume you decleard a variable named document accidentaly or intentional.

```
<body>
    <div id = 'demo'></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
        const document = "hi there";
        console.log(document);
    </script> 
</body>
```

you will endup in a **SyntaxError**: redeclaration of non-configurable global property document.

But if your desire is to declear a variable name documet you can do it by using IFFE.

```
<body>
    <div id = 'demo'></div>
    <script>
        (function(){
            const document = "hi there";
            this.document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
            console.log(document);
        })();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    </script> 
</body>
```

Output:

[image]

Let's try by an another example, suppose we have an calculator object like bellow-

```
<body>
    <script>
        var calculator = {
            add:function(a,b){
                return a+b;
            },
            mul:function(a,b){
                return a*b;
            }
        }
        console.log(calculator.add(5,10));
    </script> 
</body>
```

Well it's working like a charm, what if we accidently re-assigne the value of calculator object.

```
<body>
    <script>
        var calculator = {
            add:function(a,b){
                return a+b;
            },
            mul:function(a,b){
                return a*b;
            }
        }
        console.log(calculator.add(5,10));
        calculator = "scientific calculator";
        console.log(calculator.mul(5,5));
    </script> 
</body>
```

yes you will endup with a TypeError: calculator.mul is not a function iffe.html

But with the help of IFFE we can create a private scope where we can create another variable name calculator and use it;

```
<body>
    <script>
        var calculator = {
            add:function(a,b){
                return a+b;
            },
            mul:function(a,b){
                return a*b;
            }
        }
        var cal = (function(){
            var calculator = {
                sub:function(a,b){
                    return a-b;
                },
                div:function(a,b){
                    return a/b;
                }
            }
            console.log(this.calculator.mul(5,10));
            console.log(calculator.sub(10,5));
            return calculator;
        })();
        console.log(calculator.add(5,10));
        console.log(cal.div(10,5));
    </script> 
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Self-executing functions are typically used to encapsulate context and avoid name collusions. Any variable that you define inside the (function(){..})() are not global.

The code

```
var same_name = 1;

var myVar = (function() {
    var same_name = 2;
    console.log(same_name);
})();

console.log(same_name);
```

produces this output:

```
2
1
```

By using this syntax you avoid colliding with global variables declared elsewhere in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Correct, the output would be 2 and then 1 because myVar would be run first

Comment: Your explanation does well in explaining function scope but falls short in explaining why it is executed immediately. Assigning it to a variable is self defeating and may also intend that it can be executed more than once. 

`var same_name = 1;  
var myVar = function() {  
    var same_name = 2;  
    console.log(same_name);  
};  
myVar();  
console.log(same_name);  
`
Would have the same result.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR: Expressions can be enclosed in parenthesis, which *would* conflict with function calling *if* the expression and block forms of `function` were combined.

I like counter-examples because they paint a great picture of the logic, and noone else listed any. You might ask, "Why can't the browser see `function(){}()` and just assume its an expression?" Let's juxtapose the issue with three examples.

```js
var x;

// Here, fibonacci is a block function
function fibonacci(x) {
    var value = x < 2 ? x : fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2);
    if (x === 9) console.log("The " + x + "th fibonacci is: " + value);
    return value;
}

(x = 9);

console.log("Value of x: " + x);
console.log("fibonacci is a(n) " + typeof fibonacci);
```

Observe how things change when we turn the function into an expression.

```js
var x;

// Here, fibonacci is a function expression
(function fibonacci(x) {
    var value = x < 2 ? x : fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2);
    if (x === 9) console.log("The " + x + "th fibonacci is: " + value);
    return value;
})

(x = 9);

console.log("Value of x: " + x);
console.log("fibonacci is a(n) " + typeof fibonacci);
```

The same thing happens when you use the not-operator instead of parenthesis because both operators turn the statement into an expression:

```js
var x;

// Here, fibonacci is a function expression
! function fibonacci(x) {
    var value = x < 2 ? x : fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2);
    if (x === 9) console.log("The " + x + "th fibonacci is: " + value);
    return value;
}

(x = 9);

console.log("Value of x: " + x);
console.log("fibonacci is a(n) " + typeof fibonacci);
```

By turning the function into an expression, it gets executed by the `(x = 9)` two lines down from it. Thanks to separate behaviors for expression functions and block functions, both examples run fine without ambiguity (specs-wise).

#### Name Scoping

Another important observation is that named block functions are visible to the entire scope, whereas function expressions are only visible to themselves. In other words, `fibonacci` is only visible to the last `console.log` when it is a block in the first example. In all three examples, `fibonacci` is visible to itself, allowing `fibonacci` to call itself, which is recursion.

#### Arrow Functions

Another aspect to the logic is arrow functions. The specs would have had to include arbitrary rules and exceptions for arrow functions if the definitions of block and expression functions were merged together:

```js
function hello() {console.log("Hello World")}
(x) => console.log("hello " + x)
console.log("If you are reading this, no errors occurred");
```

Although function blocks work fine, function expressions followed by an arrow function produce a syntax error:

```js
! function hello() {console.log("Hello World")}
(x) => console.log("hello " + x)
console.log("If you are reading this, no errors occurred");
```

Here, it is ambiguous whether the `(x)` on line two is calling the function  on the preceding line or whether it is the function arguments for an arrow function.

Note that arrow functions have been indeed to the ECMAScript standard over the years and were not a factor in the initial design of the language; my point is that a differentiation between expression and block functions helps JavaScript syntax to be a little more logical and coherent.

Answer (score 2):

Self-executing anonymous function. It's executed as soon as it is created.

One short and dummy example where this is useful is:

```
function prepareList(el){
  var list = (function(){
    var l = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
     l.push(i);
    }
    return l;
  })();

  return function (el){
    for(var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++){
      if(list[i] == el) return list[i];
    }
    return null;
  }; 
} 

var search = prepareList();
search(2);
search(3);
```

So instead of creating a list each time, you create it only once (less overhead).

Comment: As written, your search rebuilds the list on each invocation. To avoid that, you need to (1) make the list and (2) return the search function as a closure having access to the list you just made. This you can do easily using the anonymous self-invoking form. See http://jsfiddle.net/BV4bT/.

Comment: can you explain...less overhead ..i dint understand this part

Comment: Overhead mean any work performed that is not necessary. Populating an array on each function invocation is not necessary, that's why an array in the example is populated by self-exec. anonymous function for the first time only. However, it seem I've made a mistake in my own answer, see the link in George's comment for a proper example.

Answer (score 2):

It is called IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression. Here is an example to show it's syntax and usage. It is used to scope the use of variables only till the function and not beyond.

```
(function () {
  function Question(q,a,c) {
    this.q = q;
    this.a = a;
    this.c = c;
  }

  Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function() {
    console.log(this.q);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++) {
      console.log(i+": "+this.a[i]);
    }
  }

  Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(ans) {
    if (ans===this.c) {
      console.log("correct");
    } else {
      console.log("incorrect");
    }
  }

  var q1 = new Question('Is Javascript the coolest?', ['yes', 'no'], 0);
  var q2 = new Question('Is python better than Javascript?', ['yes', 'no', 'both are same'], 2);
  var q3 = new Question('Is Javascript the worst?', ['yes', 'no'], 1);

  var questions = [q1, q2, q3];

  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)

  var answer = parseInt(prompt(questions[n].displayQuestion()));
  questions[n].checkAnswer(answer);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Already many good answers here but here are my 2 cents :p

---

**You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) for:**

1. Avoiding pollution in the global namespace.

   Variables defined in IIFE (or even any normal function) don't overwrite definitions in global scope.
2. Protecting code from being accessed by outer code.

   Everything that you define within the IIFE can be only be accessed within the IIFE. It protects code from being modified by outer code. Only what you explicitly return as the result of function or set as value to outer variables is accessible by outer code.
3. Avoid naming functions that you don't need to use repeatedly.
   Though it's possible to use a named function in IIFE pattern you don't do it as there is no need to call it repeatedly, generally.
4. For [Universal Module Definitions](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) which is used in many JS libraries. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866510/building-a-javascript-library-why-use-an-iife-this-way) for details.

---

IIFE is generally used in following fashion :

```
(function(param){
   //code here
})(args);
```

You can omit the parentheses `()` around anonymous function and use [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator before anonymous function.

```
void function(param){
   //code here
}(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more use case is memoization where a cache object is not global:

```
var calculate = (function() {
  var cache = {};
  return function(a) {

    if (cache[a]) {
      return cache[a];
    } else {
      // Calculate heavy operation
      cache[a] = heavyOperation(a);
      return cache[a];
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) is a function which executes as soon as the script loads and goes away.

Consider the function below written in a file named iife.js

```
(function(){
       console.log("Hello Stackoverflow!");
   })();
```

This code above will execute as soon as you load iife.js and will print '*Hello Stackoverflow!*' on the developer tools' console.

For a Detailed explanation see [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
(function () {

})();
```

is called an **immediately invoked function expression** (IIFE).

It is called a function expression because the `( yourcode )` operator in Javascript force it into an expression. The difference between a **function expression** and a **function declaration** is the following:

```
// declaration:
function declaredFunction () {}

// expressions:

// storing function into variable
const expressedFunction = function () {}

// Using () operator, which transforms the function into an expression
(function () {})
```

An expression is simply a bunch of code which can be evaluated to **a single value**. In case of the expressions in the above example this value was a **single function object**.

After we have an expression which evaluates to a function object we then can immediately **invoke** the function object with the `()` operator. For example:

```js
(function() {

  const foo = 10;        // all variables inside here are scoped to the function block
  console.log(foo);

})();

console.log(foo);  // referenceError foo is scoped to the IIFE
```

### Why is this useful?

When we are dealing with a large code base and/or when we are importing various libraries the chance of naming conflicts increases. When we are writing certain parts of our code which is related (and thus is using the same variables) inside an IIFE all of the **variables and function names are scoped to the function brackets of the IIFE**. This reduces chances of naming conflicts and lets you name them more careless (e.g. you don't have to prefix them).

Answer (score 0):

The reason self-evoking anonymous functions are used is they should never be called by other code since they "set up" the code which IS meant to be called (along with giving scope to functions and variables).

In other words, they are like programs that "make classes', at the beginning of program. After they are instantiated (automatically), the only functions that are available are the ones returned in by the anonymous function. However, all the other 'hidden' functions are still there, along with any state (variables set during scope creation).

Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 syntax (posting for myself, as I keep landing on this page looking for a quick example):

```
// simple
const simpleNumber = (() => {
  return true ? 1 : 2
})()

// with param
const isPositiveNumber = ((number) => {
  return number > 0 ? true : false
})(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is called self-invoking function. A self-invoking (also called self-executing) function is a nameless (anonymous) function that is invoked(Called) immediately after its definition. [Read more here](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/js-self-invoking-functions.html)

What these functions do is that when the function is defined, The function is immediately called, which saves time and extra lines of code(as compared to calling it on a seperate line).

Here is an example:

```js
(function() {
    var x = 5 + 4;
    console.log(x);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

> An immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) is a function that's executed as soon as it's created. It has no connection with any events or asynchronous execution. You can define an IIFE as shown below:

```
(function() {
     // all your code here
     // ...
})();
```

> The first pair of parentheses function(){...} converts the code inside the parentheses into an expression.The second pair of parentheses calls the function resulting from the expression.

An `IIFE` can also be described as a self-invoking anonymous function. Its most common usage is to limit the scope of a variable made via var or to encapsulate context to avoid name collisions.

Answer (score -1):

This is a more in depth explanation of why you would use this:

"The primary reason to use an IIFE is to obtain data privacy. Because JavaScript's var scopes variables to their containing function, any variables declared within the IIFE cannot be accessed by the outside world."

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html

Answer (score -2):

Normally, JavaScript code has global scope in the application. When we declare global variable in it, there is a chance for using the same duplicate variable  in some other area of the development for some other purpose. Because of this duplication there may happen some error. So we can avoid this global variables by using immediately invoking function expression , this expression is self-executing expression.When we make our code inside this **IIFE** expression global variable will be like local scope and local variable.

Two ways we can create **IIFE**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myModule", []);
}());
```

OR

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myModule", []);
})();
```

In the code snippet above, “*var app*” is a local variable now.

Answer (score -3):

Usually, we don't invoke a function immediately after we write it in the program. 
In extremely simple terms, when you call a function right after its creation, it is called IIFE - a fancy name.